# GItHub Actions: How to run integration tests workflow after workflows for individual (sub)projects in a monorepo?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, cd

Inspired by [this](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2023-07-13-python-monorepo-2/) article about Python monorepo and GitHub Actions, I want to migrate from GitLab CI to GitHub Actions.

I currently operate with the following stages in GitLab: `test`, `deploy`, `integrationtest`, and `release`.

How can I run the integration tests in GitHub Actions only after all workflows for the individual (sub)projects have completed? The article runs several workflows, with `paths:` triggers, but I don't want the integration tests to run for each (sub)project, but for all of them collectively.

How can I achieve this?

Monorepo example: https://github.com/tweag/python-monorepo-example